# How to split the below string in C# and save it in a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For Eg. This is the string

```
  Engs.[EngagementDeliveryStatusTxt] ASC
```

How to split the string using C# and save it in a variable ?

I want to split eng , EngagementDeliveryStatusTxt and ASC and save it using a variable.No criteria.

Answer (score 3):

You can add multuple delimiters to a `char[]` and use that in `String.Split`:

```
string text = "Engs.[EngagementDeliveryStatusTxt] ASC";
char[] delimiters = { '.', '[', ']', ' ' };
string[] result = text.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You now have one variable, you access each string via index, f.e. in a for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    string part = result[i];
}
```

or with LINQ, f.e. if you want the first:

```
string firstPart = result.FirstOrDefault(); // null if the array is empty
```

Comment: Is there any other way without delimiters ? @Tim Schmelter

Comment: @raghav there is no more simple answer. You can use RegEx or a loop but in every case you need delimiters. You should accept this answer.

Comment: @raghav: [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) has several overloads, but all share that they "return a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are **delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array**". Maybe you have misunderstood how it works or you haven't explained your requirement well.

Comment: What is the use of StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries @TimSchmelter

Comment: @raghav: that will skip all strings which are `String.Empty`(`""`). That can happen if your delimiter is a space(`" "`) and there are multiple consecutive spaces. So you can be sure that the array doesn't contain empty strings.

Comment: Can you explain char[] delimiters = { '.', '[', ']', ' ' }; @TimSchmelter

Comment: @raghav: that's one way to declare and initialize an array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601(v=vs.71).aspx
A `char` is a single letter or digit from a string. So `"foo"` is a string and `'f'` is the first char. You can get a char[] from a string with `"foo".ToCharArray()`.